# is x/x a proper or improper fraction?

Tags: definition

If the numerator is greater than the denominator, it's improper. The other way around, it's proper. What if the numerator is the same as the denominator?

Comment: At primary school I learned about “frazione propria, impropria e apparente” (proper, improper and apparent fraction), the last for the case $n/n$. I've never found a real use for the terminology, so I wouldn't bother at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, it doesn't matter. It comes down to a matter of convention. In fact, I've never heard of the terms, proper, improper (or, especially, apparent) fractions anywhere beyond primary school. No theorems apply exclusively, for example, to proper fractions. Hence it's best to just use whatever definition you like; if you feel that $10/10$ is improper, then say it so, otherwise, say it's proper. You do you, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search yields [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/improper-fractions.html) site that clearly says (emphasis added):

> An Improper Fraction has a top number larger than (**or equal to**) the
>   bottom number.

Answer (score 1):

The term "fraction" (from the Latin *frangere*, "to break") essentially *means* "fragment". A *proper* fraction, then, is one that that respects this intention, representing a fragment of the unit.

The unit itself is clearly a special case; I suspect textbook definitions lean toward calling $x/x$ an *improper* fraction, perhaps because the unbroken whole isn't usually what comes to mind when one thinks of a "fragment". Reasonable people may disagree, however, so keep an open mind.

Consider, for instance, these entries from the "Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics" (EKU) pages ...

> [IMPROPER FRACTION](http://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html) was used in English in 1542 by Robert Recorde in *The ground of artes, teachyng the worke and practise of arithmetike*: "An Improper Fraction...that is to saye, a fraction in forme, which in dede is greater than a Unit." [Under [FRACTION](http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html), EKU notes that Recorde wrote "A Fraction in deede is a broken number", which recalls the notion of a fragment.]

... but also ...

> [PROPER FRACTION](http://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html) appears in English in 1674 in Samuel Jeake *Arithmetic* (1701): "Proper Fractions always have the Numerator less than the Denominator, for then the parts signified are less than a Unit or Integer" (OED2).

Interestingly, EKU doesn't cite either of these sources as explicitly defining the *opposite* terms; perhaps they did. (EKU isn't an absolute authority.) In any case, if we interpret the given citations such that anything that isn't "improper" is "proper", and vice-versa, then these authors differ in their classification of the unit.

---

In a comment to the question, @egreg notes that "apparent fraction" applies to $x/x$. I've never heard of this term. EKU doesn't have it, nor does (English) Wikipedia. I finally tracked-down this definition via [Answers.com](http://science.answers.com/Q/What_is_an_apparent_fraction) and thought I'd share it ...

> An apparent fraction is a fraction with one of the following properties:
>
> - The numerator and denominator are the same (eg 2/2 or 10/10)
> - The denominator is one (eg 4/1 or 20/1)
> - The numerator is a multiple of the denominator (eg 4/2 or 10/5)

So, it seems that an apparent fraction is simply an integer that *appears* in fractional form. I guess it's nice that there's a word for such a thing, but I'm with @egreg: I don't know that I'd have much use for it.